# How to redirect wildcard route by condition in angular routing module

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-routing

Is there the way to handle redirect route when user type the wrong URL using wildcard but control by condition?

My project have 3 main modules separately, and every each one of them have some condition that can only access by user's roles.

the problem is i don't know how to handle it by condition, i've tried canActivate but it doesn't work

> main.ts:14 Error: Invalid configuration of route '**'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

Here some of my code.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'customer1'
},
{
    path: 'customer1',
    component: RootOneComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'home'
        },
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeOneComponent
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            component: PageNotFoundComponent
        }
    ],
},
{
    path: 'customer2',
    component: RootTwoComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'home'
        },
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeTwoComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'BlogPicture',
            loadChildren: () => import('./blog/blog.module').then(m => m.BlogModule)
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            component: PageNotFoundComponent
        }
    ],
},
{
    path: 'customer3',
    component: RootThreeComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'home'
        },
        {
            path: 'home',
            component: HomeThreeComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'blog-price',
            loadChildren: () => import('./blog/blog.module').then(m => m.BlogModule)
        },
        {
            path: '**',
            component: PageNotFoundComponent
        }
    ],
},
 // wild card condition is there the way to manage this?
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'classic'
}
```

];

Answer (score 0):

**In your app.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: "customer1",
    component: FirstCustomerModule,
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "customer2",
    data: { preload: true },
    loadChildren: () => SecondCustomerModule
  },
  {
    path: "customer3",
    data: { preload: true },
    loadChildren: () => ThirdCustomerModule
  }
}
```

path defines you mentioned path and in module you have to mention that mentioned module will be hit . Then in your Modules you have to relatively mention path , I have mentioned just app level routing , then you can further implement module level routing , Load Children tells our app that it is a module and it have further components

Comment: for conditions use this : if(condition)
{

 this.router.navigate(["/whatever"]); 

}

Comment: oh yeah, i forgot to update my code following Angular v.8

Comment: I just updated my code, could you please take another look?

Comment: use component by replacing redirectTo at the end

Comment: if you want to do with redirect then add pathMatch = "full"

Comment: if path miss match, it should redirect to where the user belong in the module.

You see in the wild card { path: '**', redirectTo: 'some url that control by condition'}

is it can be done?